# Whenever i click next or prev on my image slider it scrolls to the top of page how do i stop this?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "Slider",
  data() {
    return {
      images: [
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/12/15/24/amsterdam-1089646_1280.jpg",
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/17/23/03/usa-1206240_1280.jpg",
        "../assets/sample-1.jpg"
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/04/19/30/berlin-cathedral-1882397_1280.jpg"
      ],
      
      currentIndex: 0
    };
  },


  methods: {
 

    next: function() {
      this.currentIndex += 1;
    },
    prev: function() {
      this.currentIndex -= 1;
    }
  },

  computed: {
    currentImg: function() {
      return this.images[Math.abs(this.currentIndex) % this.images.length];
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

vue.js below

```
<template>
 <div>
    <transition-group name="fade" tag="div">
      <div v-for="i in [currentIndex]" :key="i">
        <img :src="currentImg" />
      </div>
    </transition-group>
    <a class="prev" @click="prev" href="#">&#10094; Previous</a>
    <a class="next" @click="next" href="#">&#10095; Next</a>
    </div>
```

Just scrolls to the top every time i click on either prev or next can't figure out why.
Also i havent been able to get any of my own images from assets to appear in the slider and not sure why it isnt able to retrieve them this way (as in the sample-1.jpg) Thanks.

Comment: Remove `href="#"`

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `href="#"`
2. You dont need `v-for` or `transition-group`. A simple `transition` with `mode="out-in"` is enough. You put the `key` to the current image, so vue always knows if the image gets replaced so it can do a transition

Dont put images into the `assets` folder. You better put it into the `static` folder.

Then you can access your image like `/sample-1.jpg`

```js
new Vue({
  name: "Slider",
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      images: [
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/12/15/24/amsterdam-1089646_1280.jpg",
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/17/23/03/usa-1206240_1280.jpg",
        "/sample-1.jpg",
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/04/19/30/berlin-cathedral-1882397_1280.jpg"
      ],
      currentIndex: 0
    };
  },
})
```

```css
.v-enter-active,
.v-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.v-enter,
.v-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <a class="prev" @click="currentIndex--" v-if="currentIndex > 0">&#10094; Previous</a>
    <a class="next" @click="currentIndex++" v-if="currentIndex < images.length - 1">&#10095; Next</a>
    <transition name="v" mode="out-in">
        <img :key="images[currentIndex]" :src="images[currentIndex]" />
    </transition>
  
</div>
```